# Is there an experimental set up that would produce a "macroscopic" a weak or strong nuclear force fields?

Tags: yang-mills, classical-field-theory, electroweak, thought-experiment, strong-force

I was wondering if there is an experimental set up that would produce something equivalent to a classical electromagnetic field for the weak and strong nuclear forces. I know that the those forces are short range due to the mediators of the weakforce having mass and due to confinement for the strong force, but I was wondering if some loophole might still allow for such a thing.
Here are some ideas of directions to investigate:

Since electromagnetism and the weak interaction are unified at high energies, would that implies that in some extreme conditions (to be defined...), there could be such a thing as an "electroweak classical/macroscopic field" ? How would it behave, and how would it affect say an electron and a neutrino ?

Also even for low energies (i.e when the symmetry is broken and the weak force is short range), could there be some special arrangement of weak "source" charges that counter-balances the exponentiel decay of the Yukawa field, in such a way that its effect might be mesurable on a test charge, without it having to collide with the source charges ? A similar question could be asked of the strong force.

A last idea would be to consider extreme objects such as neutron stars. Would their extreme density be sufficient to make the Yukawa field noticeable ?

Comment: There are more than one questions here. It is recommended to ask one question per post

Comment: If you are thinking of the neutron star as a humongous nucleus with a huge weak charge, it has a macroscopic range, so your proposed enhancement of a weak Z halo fails.

Comment: One would certainly "notice" the presence of neutron star matter, but I don't understand how it would make either the weak or the strong force longer range than they are inside a nucleus. The electromagnetic force has infinite range because it is mediated by a massless field. That's not the case here. You answered your own question right away.

Answer (score -2):

I will answer one of the two questions in the title, namely 'Is there an experimental set up that would produce a macroscopic strong nuclear force fields?'.

A [neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star) is such a setup. On a neutron star macroscopic amounts of matter are held together by the strong interaction. Fortunately we cannot make such (macroscopic) matter in a lab but we can study it from a safe distance with astronomic devices and who knows, if one is discovered nearby, someday with a space mission.

Comment: @downvoters I stopped reading after the first five or so questions.